# How do i create structure of structure in python ?

Tags: python-3.x

I want the below C structure to be implemented in python and want to have  access to  members as mentioned below. Any help is appreciated

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int ch_state;
    unsigned int polling;
    unsigned int timeout;
    unsigned int count;
}channel_Status_t;

typedef struct{
 channel_Status_t  ch_status;
}channel_num_t

typedef struct{   
    channel_num_t SR1;
    channel_num_t SR2;
    channel_num_t LR1;
    channel_num_t LR2;
} channel_type_t;

channel_type_t Rx;
channel_type_t Tx;

Rx.SR1.ch_status.ch_state=1;
Rx.SR1.ch_status.polling=10;
Rx.SR1.ch_status.polling=20;
Rx.SR1.ch_status.count=0;

// Should be able to access data as below... 
Rx.SR2.ch_status.ch_state=1;
Rx.SR2.ch_status.polling=10;
Rx.SR2.ch_status.polling=20;
Rx.SR2.ch_status.count=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to make a class out of each of those structs.